# Can changes in a magnetic field travel easily over large distances?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

Here's what I did: I directed a laser onto a mirror that is hanging by a thread. The mirror is attached to the thread by two small magnets. The reflected beam of the laser is directed to a target. I then moved a hand held magnet in front of the mirror. The  magnets on the mirror responded by moving. Their movements were amplified by the laser, much the same way that a small movement of a rifle sight can mean large distances the farther the bullet travels. Also, the law of reflection doubles the movement too. So the result is a very sensitive device
Here's a close up of the mirror;[image]
Here's the entire setup:[image]
I posted a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk1X1w_JhJo) for additional info.
The fields that I tested display great ranges. A small ceramic magnet has a field that reaches out to 100 feet. Small voltages produced measurable fields out several meters. The project left me with so many question, but I will narrow it to #1 below.

1. These results surprised me due to the fact that I was able to detect the fields interacting at distances in the 100 foot range for basic magnets, and close to three meters for a 1.5 volt battery sending current through a small loop of wire. Do these observations seem right? I can't come up with a more specific question other than are these the results one should expect? Are they reasonable?

Note: The video shows the observations.

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. Your question should be self-contained. It should not be necessary to watch a video to make sense of what you are asking. eg There is no description here of what you observed, what fields you measured and how you measured them.

Comment: My field tester showed that a field moved a mirror, so question one was looking for confirmation of that. The mirrors moved even when the fields were separated by 60 feet or more, so question two was looking for confirmation of that. I respectfully disagree with your statement. "It should not be necessary to watch a video to make sense of what you are asking." Why? Why limit our communications to typed words on a screen?

Comment: What field did you test? How was this test made? And why limit our communications to videos? The site policy is that questions should be self-contained : videos and web links can be useful for providing additional detail or evidence, but the gyst of your question should be found in your text. See [How to deal with questions based on videos](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4918/).

Comment: I spent a lot of time working on a way to measure electromagnetic fields. The method I came up with works really well.  It picks up a cheap ceramic magnet at 100 feet away. It detects the field created by a 1.5 volt AA battery at 11 feet.  You should watch the video. It's on YouTube.  I am trying to gain new insight into how fields work. This experiment showed me that a field and its source are tied together more that I ever thought.  My question posed here was to get opinions from professionals. Are my results as surprising to them as they are to me.

Comment: The questions here seem to be unrelated to your experiment, even if they were brought up by it...is the extra information really necessary?

Comment: I am not criticising your effort, which is admirable, and the question deserves an answer because the effect is surprising : the force between magnetic dipoles decreases as $1/r^4$, so I am very surprised that any effect is seen above 1m away. Perhaps this unexpected result, and your title, gives an impression that you are challenging the correctness of established physics ... I recommend that you change your title to eg "Can changes in a magnetic field travel easily over large distances?" Also include in your text a brief description of what you did in your experiment and what you observed.

Comment: You could increase the value of your experiment by comparing the deflection you observe with that when the magnet is stationary and about 20 cm from the mirror and to one side.  (You may have to tether the thread in a vertical line to ensure there is only a rotational deflection and no lateral deflection.)

Comment: @sammygerbil Sammy, I resubmitted based on your recommended language. Maybe you can make this into a totally new question because it's quite different from the original. That way it will get more exposure. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have voted to reopen your question. It was not necessary to remove the video, which provides useful additional information. Your two original questions were also ok. The weakness of your new question is that it is vague and seeks a subjective response, which is *off topic*. It would be better to state why the results surprise you (eg force between 2 magnets is negligible at more than about 10cm) and to ask for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun experiment! I haven't run any numbers for whether the amplitude of oscillation you see seems plausibly caused by the magnetic fields generated by your handheld magnets, but I'll just answer your two questions.

1. Yes, magnetic fields are "tied to their source" in the sense that if the source moves, the magnetic field in its vicinity must also change. It's also true that if you introduce another source of magnetic fields, in this case the magnet you're moving with your hand, it will exert a force and a torque on the magnet you've hung from the string. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets) for more details.
2. The fields do extend to infinity, in principle, though of course decreasing as the distance from the source increases. A rapid movement of the source would not cause the distant fields to "move" at speeds beyond $c$, however. I think that the concept of movement for a magnetic field is not so well defined, but I understand what you're saying. The answer is that changes in the field propagate at the speed of light. I'd recommend [this book](https://g.co/kgs/z5yID7) for more information.

As an aside, if you'd like to compare the angular displacement you observe with what you can expect from theory, you'll need to know the torsional spring constant of the wire with which you hung the mirror, and the total magnetic moment of each of your magnets. The motion of your handheld magnet exerts an oscillating torque on the hanging magnet, which acts as a driven harmonic oscillator. The amplitude you observe will depend on the torsional spring constant, the applied torque, the moment of inertia of your mirror+magnet assembly, and the damping.